buildozer error while trying to deploy an apk app
when using buildozer I get the following error message. i am new to using buildozer so I dont know. how can I fix it? I've tried to reinstall python3 and python3-dev (because it looked to me that this may be the problem) but it didnt help. maybe the problem is in the other parts of the log outside the error message, I dont knoe. i am completely new. any help would be much apprichiated. you can find the full error log (where the errors are stated) here https://github.com/shlomihagadol/Buildozer_error
[WARNING]: ERROR: /home/vboxuser/106/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/hostpython3/desktop/hostpython3/native-build/python3 failed!

# Command failed: ('/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pythonforandroid.toolchain', 'create', '--dist_name=myapp', '--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python3,kivy,hashlib,socket,threading,time,ast,datetime,decimal,geopy,unicodedata,psycopg2-binary,plyer', '--arch=arm64-v8a', '--arch=armeabi-v7a', '--copy-libs', '--color=always', '--storage-dir=/home/vboxuser/106/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a', '--ndk-api=21', '--ignore-setup-py', '--debug')
# Error code: 1
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/xaxa:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1390,unix/xaxa:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1390'
#     QT_ACCESSIBILITY = '1'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg'
#     SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER = 'gnome-keyring'
#     XDG_MENU_PREFIX = 'gnome-'
#     GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID = 'this-is-deprecated'
#     LANGUAGE = 'en_IL:en'
#     GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE = 'ubuntu'
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh'
#     XMODIFIERS = '@im=ibus'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     GTK_MODULES = 'gail:atk-bridge'
#     PWD = '/home/vboxuser/106'
#     LOGNAME = 'vboxuser'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'wayland'
#     SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = '1423'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.W7VJM2'
#     HOME = '/home/vboxuser'
#     USERNAME = 'vboxuser'
#     IM_CONFIG_PHASE = '1'
#     LANG = 'en_IL'
#     LS_COLORS = 'rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:.tar=01;31:.tgz=01;31:.arc=01;31:.arj=01;31:.taz=01;31:.lha=01;31:.lz4=01;31:.lzh=01;31:.lzma=01;31:.tlz=01;31:.txz=01;31:.tzo=01;31:.t7z=01;31:.zip=01;31:.z=01;31:.dz=01;31:.gz=01;31:.lrz=01;31:.lz=01;31:.lzo=01;31:.xz=01;31:.zst=01;31:.tzst=01;31:.bz2=01;31:.bz=01;31:.tbz=01;31:.tbz2=01;31:.tz=01;31:.deb=01;31:.rpm=01;31:.jar=01;31:.war=01;31:.ear=01;31:.sar=01;31:.rar=01;31:.alz=01;31:.ace=01;31:.zoo=01;31:.cpio=01;31:.7z=01;31:.rz=01;31:.cab=01;31:.wim=01;31:.swm=01;31:.dwm=01;31:.esd=01;31:.jpg=01;35:.jpeg=01;35:.mjpg=01;35:.mjpeg=01;35:.gif=01;35:.bmp=01;35:.pbm=01;35:.pgm=01;35:.ppm=01;35:.tga=01;35:.xbm=01;35:.xpm=01;35:.tif=01;35:.tiff=01;35:.png=01;35:.svg=01;35:.svgz=01;35:.mng=01;35:.pcx=01;35:.mov=01;35:.mpg=01;35:.mpeg=01;35:.m2v=01;35:.mkv=01;35:.webm=01;35:.webp=01;35:.ogm=01;35:.mp4=01;35:.m4v=01;35:.mp4v=01;35:.vob=01;35:.qt=01;35:.nuv=01;35:.wmv=01;35:.asf=01;35:.rm=01;35:.rmvb=01;35:.flc=01;35:.avi=01;35:.fli=01;35:.flv=01;35:.gl=01;35:.dl=01;35:.xcf=01;35:.xwd=01;35:.yuv=01;35:.cgm=01;35:.emf=01;35:.ogv=01;35:.ogx=01;35:.aac=00;36:.au=00;36:.flac=00;36:.m4a=00;36:.mid=00;36:.midi=00;36:.mka=00;36:.mp3=00;36:.mpc=00;36:.ogg=00;36:.ra=00;36:.wav=00;36:.oga=00;36:.opus=00;36:.spx=00;36:.xspf=00;36:'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'ubuntu:GNOME'
#     VTE_VERSION = '6800'
#     WAYLAND_DISPLAY = 'wayland-0'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN = '/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/1b44396b_6c1b_4acc_bc19_1de6b523408f'
#     GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY = ':1'
#     LESSCLOSE = '/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     LESSOPEN = '| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s'
#     USER = 'vboxuser'
#     GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE = ':1.109'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     QT_IM_MODULE = 'ibus'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     PATH = '/home/vboxuser/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin'
#     GDMSESSION = 'ubuntu'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     _ = '/usr/local/bin/buildozer'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/vboxuser'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/vboxuser/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/vboxuser/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/vboxuser/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r25b'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '31'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2

